# The concise way to imply that 'our group has five people' in the subject position of a sentence

Tags: expressions, phrases

If I would like to convey that '**our group has five people**' without describing it in a separate sentence, but rather implying it in the subject position of a sentence. How can I express the sentence?

For example, will the usage such as '**Our five-membered group does something..**' work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the requirement is to avoid *a second sentence* stating the number of members of the group:

> Our group, *which has five members*, will meet on Thursday.
>
> *The five members of our group* will meet on Thursday.
>
> *The five of us* will meet on Thursday.
>
> *Our group of five* will meet on Thursday (per PMV's suggestion).

*Our five-membered group* ... is grammatical but not idiomatic.  The pattern itself (cardinal-number + PP + noun) is OK:

> a three-cornered hat,  a five-sided building, a six-legged insect

But "membered" as an attribute of a group sounds odd.

Comment: As a native speaker, I like your third option "The five of us" the best.  If you really had to use the word "group", I'd opt for a different alternative you didn't have on here - "Our group of five will meet on Thursday".

Comment: @PMV: added your good suggestion as another idiomatic choice.